# vector array - sorting failure

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, vector

I have problem with sorting an array. I don't know why my codes does not sort an array properly. I am new in programming so be gentle on me. Here's a code. Also other functions like merge or quick sort does not work too. Thanks in advance for answer.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <vector>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <iterator>

std::vector<int> bubbleSort(std::vector<int>& Array)
{
for (unsigned int j = 1; j < Array.size() - 1; ++j)
{

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Array.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        if (Array[i] > Array[++i])
        {
            std::swap(Array[i], Array[++i]);

        }
    }
}
return Array;
}


int main()
{

for (int i = 0; i < 10;i++)
{

int N;  //array size
srand(std::time(NULL));
std::cout << " array size: ";
std::cin >> N;
std::vector <int> Array;

 //fill array
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    Array.push_back(i);

for (int i = N - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    int j = rand() % i;
    std::swap(Array[i], Array[j]);
  }
bubbleSort(Array);
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Array.size(); i++)
    {
    std::cout << Array.at(i) << std::endl;
    }

  }
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `if (Array[i] > Array[++i])` -- don't try to be too clever.

Comment: If I may ask, what do you mean?

Comment: Okay, I found my mistake in iteration, it should start from 
       for (unsigned int j = 0; j < Array.size() - 1; ++j)

Comment: Does `std::swap` need a pointer?  You are passing it values.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're unintentionally incrementing `i` within the loop.  Don't use `++i`, use `i+1` instead.  Also change your loop termination condition to just `i < Array.size()` instead of `i < Array.size() - 1`